# Change Report Type Based Upon Drop Down in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, dropdownbox

I have a report that will have an parameter specifing rather it should be a chart or table. What I want to do is simplly hide and show the proper element based upon the value they select in that drop down. Is this possible, and if so how would I go about it?

Comment: Do u want to set the visibility property on the chart based on the parameter ?

Comment: Correct and I want to do the same thing for the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
IIf(Parameters!YourParameterName.Value == "Something", True, False)
```

The above expression should be written in the visibility property of the table

Comment: That worked thank you very much. In case someone else needs this there are two minor corrections is should be =IIF... and should be = "Something" not == "Something".